# Find the minimum value of C subject to the given constraints.

Tags: linear-programming, systems-of-equations

C=2x+5y
Constraints:
x+y>=2
2x-3y<=-6
3x-2y>=6

A-42
B-4
C-49
D-10

I encountered this question while doing the Systems of Linear Equations and Inequalities test at http://www.classzone.com/books/algebra_2/chapterquiz_national.cfm. It seemed easy enough. So I graphed the inequalities on desmos.com and this is what I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkLRS.png
So I plugged (6,6) into C=2x+5y, and ended up with C=42. However, at the end of the test, it said that the correct answer is 4. I'm unsure what I did wrong, and hopefully you can explain it to me.

Comment: The link to the problem is retired. Given the problem as you wrote it, I agree with you because the feasibility region is the triangular region with $(6,6)$ as its corner point.

Answer (score 0):

The answer should be $42$. We can see that $4$ is not correct as an answer because there is no $(x,y)\in\mathbb R$ such that $2x+5y=4$.

If $$2x+5y=4\iff y=-\frac{2}{5}x+\frac 45,$$then
we have
$$x+y\ge 2\iff x+\left(-\frac{2}{5}x+\frac 45\right)\ge 2\iff x\ge 2$$
and 
$$2x-3y\le -6\iff 2x-3\left(-\frac{2}{5}x+\frac 45\right)\le -6\iff x\le -\frac 98.$$
There is no $x\in\mathbb R$ such that "$x\ge 2\ \text{and}\ x\le -\frac 98$".

In the same way as above, we can see that there is no $(x,y)\in\mathbb R$ such that $2x+5y=10.$ On the other hand, since $2\times 6+5\times 6=42$, we can choose $42$ as an answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. There was also another problem on that test that I'm going to make a question about. If it turns out that the website was wrong about that one too, I don't suppose I'll use that website anymore.

Comment: @user50328: You are welcome!